# Adding httpHeaderSecurity for all the Tomcat Applications

Tags: tomcat

I currently add my security headers like so, inside the application's WEB-INF folder, in the web.xml file:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>httpHeaderSecurity</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter</filter-class>
    <async-supported>true</async-supported>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>antiClickJackingOption</param-name>
        <param-value>SAMEORIGIN</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>httpHeaderSecurity</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Is there a way to generalize this, so that I can have it on a server level, for multiple applications? I was thinking maybe using Tomcat Valves to add it in the server.xml? Is that possible? Any suggestions?